# remove column from variable (LINQ)

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have defined the following variable

var result = from report in firoozehDataContext.Reports select report;

now if i want delete One of the columns in the variable, how do i it?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to select all but one of the columns or that you want to change the value of one of the columns?

Comment: no, first i want select all column's from table, then filter that column's which user want to display in result according to selected checkboxe's

Comment: @Sadegh: How are you displaying the data to the user? Are you using, for example, WinForms or ASP.NET? What control are you using? There are effectively two ways to solve this problem. Only pull down the columns you need and bind that to the control, or use the controls built-in capabilities to hide and unhide columns (if the control you are using doesn't have these features then get a new control).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have grave concerns about performance, this seems like the kind of thing that should be handled at the UI level and not in your data access code.

I get the impression that you are taking the results of this query and binding to a grid or list with auto-generated columns.  However, it is much easier (and safer) to control which columns are visible in a grid than it is to dynamically build a SQL SELECT query.  Auto-generated columns are really only appropriate for scaffolding scenarios.

Another good reason why I would recommend against doing what you're doing is that every time your end user decides to hide (or re-show) another column, you're forced to re-run your entire query.  This is almost certainly not what you really want.

I would simply select all the columns that *could* be available and hide the ones that *shouldn't* be available as part of the UI code.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Dynamic Linq Library](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/bb894665.aspx)

Description related to Linq2Sql by [Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

You are interested in the part about dynamic return values.